# Read documents from Google Firestore console Fee issue

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I'm studying Firestore. is in use. Is it right that I am charged when I read the document from the console? The problem is that when you read documents from the console, do you charge for reading all the documents in the subcollection.. For example.

Let's say there's a sub-collection in a document and there's 100,000 documents in that sub-collection.

Then, do I have to charge 100,000 reading fees if I read only that one document on console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it right that I am charged when I read the document from the console?

Yes, you have to pay for each document you read in the Firebase Console. The Console is considered a client as any other web, iOS, or Android client.

> The problem is that when you read documents from the console, do you charge for reading all the documents in the subcollection?

No, you have to pay only for the first 30. I'm not sure about the number, it may be 40 or even 50 but for sure not the entire sub-collection. That's because there is a pagination mechanism implemented, so you can load the documents progressively. So each time you scroll you get another 30 documents until you read the last one.

Comment: Hey Swift Starter. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So I'll just read 30 documents in the first collection

2nd and 3rd collections don't charge for reading?

Because the focus is only on the first collection.

Comment: If you select only one collection, yes, you'll only pay for 30 documents. You'll don't have to pay reads from other collections unless you explicitly select them.

Comment: So did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thank you, Alex. Let me ask you one more question. :-)

I'm making a chat app with firestore using streambuilder with flutter

I'm setting a limit of 25 lasted message. If a new message is added

The list will be updated

25 + 25 = 50 charges?

Or is it going to be 25 + 1 = 26?

Comment: If you're using a [persistent listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), then you'll have to pay a read operation for every new message.

Comment: Suppose I was subscribed to the latest 20 messages in date order.

But let's assume that one of those messages was deleted and the 21st message came in as number 20.

Then, will the reading fee be added one more time here? Or maybe 20 + 20?

Comment: If the 21st document falls in the query due to the deletion of the 20th, then you'll have to pay for a new read. The others are read from the cache.

Comment: So in this case, only one reading fee will be added, right?

Comment: Yes, but only if you use a persistent listener.